# Is there any way to customize telerik radmenuitem header in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, radmenu

I'm trying to customize a header in radmenuitem to have header and infoicon in leftside of header, but I couldn't achieve it because text binding is not working.
Also I have an icon at left which is like
consider this for ref which I want ---  "icon  header   infoicon"

I tried this code

```
 <telerik:RadMenuItem
      Command="{Binding }"
      CommandParameter="{Binding}"
     <telerik:RadMenuItem.IconTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
           <image/>
            </DataTemplate>
     </telerik:RadMenuItem.IconTemplate>
     <telerik:RadMenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
           <stackpanel>
          <textblock text="{binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}                                               ,path=datacontext.text ,updatsourcetrigger=propertychanged,mode=twoway/>
           <image/
         </DataTemplate>
         </stackpanel
      </telerik:RadMenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
      <telerik:RadMenuItem.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadMenuItem}"/>
      </<telerik:RadMenuItem.Style>
</telerik:RadMenuItem>`
```

expected to happen
(icon  header  infoicon)

I'm getting like this
(icon infoicon) header is missing